# Swift how to know if json key is null or no key?

Tags: json, swift, struct, key-value

I have a struct that reflects the data from nesed JSON with nilable variables.

```
struct JsonReceived: Decodable {
    let data: JsonReceivedData
}

struct JsonReceivedData: Decodable {
    let key1: String?
    let key2: String?
    let key3: String?
    let key4: String?
    let key5: String?
}
```

then I encode the json by `JSONDecoder` and send it's data to the function.

```
let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(JsonReceived.self, from: data)

self.addData(res.data.key1)
self.addData(res.data.key2)
self.addData(res.data.key3)
self.addData(res.data.key4)
self.addData(res.data.key5)
```

The problem is, sometimes the JSON data was look like this

```
{
    "data": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key3": "value3",
        "key5": null,
    }
}
```

and I don't want to send the data from the function if the key doesn't exist,

As you can see in my JSON sample, there is no `key2` and `key4` key value pair, so I don't want to send them to the function, the `key5` is null but still it have a key, so I want it to send to the function even if it's null.

I want the output will something like this.

```
if isHaveAkeyFromJSON(res.data.key2) {
    self.addData(res.data.key2)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "don't want to send the data from the function if the key doesn't exist"? Where are you sending the data?

Comment: @PGDev what I mean is I want to do something when the key is existed even if it's value is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res` doesn't know how it was created.  Key's with values have valued, and those that don't don't.  You need to look at the receive JSON again if you want that information.

```
let testDictionary = try decoder.decode([String: String?].self, from: data)
```

then test the dictionary for the key:

```
if testDictionary.keys.contains(res.key2) {
    self.addData(res.key2)
}
```

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I think there's something missing in my question, the `JsonReceived` was inside the nested json data, I'll gonna edit the question to be clear

Comment: I finally fix it by the structure of this answer, I just changed the docoder to `try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject]`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the structs for other things then you can decode and call your method in once

```
struct JsonReceived: Codable {
    let data: [String: String?]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        data = try container.decode([String: String?].self, forKey: .data)
        data.values.forEach {
            self.addData($0)
        }
    }
}
```